# Background image issue in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Here is my CSS:

```
#menu {
    float: left;
    background: url(images/menu_normal.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    display: inline;
    background: url(images/menu_hover.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id = "menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Movies</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Clubs</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Concerts</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Parties</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The background image for `a:hover` is not displayed in Chrome and Safari.
I found something about WebKit bug, but is it really and if yes, how could it be fixed?

Here is the URL:
http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/feasibility/statue.html

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a typo that your CSS is missing the '#' on the menu tags

Comment: @Joe, that was bad formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    background: transparent; /* IE6 will love this! */
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background: transparent url(images/menu_hover.jpg) repeat-x bottom; /* oh, oh, a fix here, transparent added */
}
```

<strike>I'd do it similar to this.</strike>

But without a real example, I have hard time judging this. Same as Michael, if doesn't work, let me know.

Plus, jsFiddle or a link to actual site would be nice.

Okay, I made an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/dpCwp/

As you can see, there is your version of code in `div#bugged` which is not working and, mine - `div#fixed`. Yes, they use no images, but as you can see `#bugged` doesn't work with colors anyway.

**And just in case, a working version with image for background** - http://jsfiddle.net/dpCwp/3/

Huh, and just tested on [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)`6/7/8/9` and with newest versions of [opera](/questions/tagged/opera), [safari](/questions/tagged/safari), [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) — works like a charm (except the delay when loading remote image..)

And just to make things clearer... that's in no way a bug related to [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) or whatever, that's improper use of [css](/questions/tagged/css)!

### Updated, to reflect your actual CSS

*Your CSS*

---

```
#menu {
    float: left;
    background: url(images/menu_normal.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    /*background: url("../images/menu_normal.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    display: inline;
    background: url(images/menu_hover.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

#menu a:active {
    display: inline;
    background: url(images/menu_active.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}
```

*Must be replaced to:*

---

```
#menu {
    float: left;
    background: url(images/menu_normal.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /* lots of useless stuff have been removed from this rule and moved to next rule (#menu li a) */
}

#menu li a {
    /* you haven't added this rule in your CSS, it's essential! */
    display: block;
    background: transparent; /* IE6 will love this! */
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    /* see properties added from #menu li, to here... */
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background: transparent url(images/menu_hover.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    /* useless stuff removed again */
}

#menu li a:active {
    background: transparent url(images/menu_active.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
    /* and we don't need those tags here again... */
}
```

---

1. The CSS properties I removed were essential, and those which I added too. Same for rules!
2. I've removed all the properties from `:hover`, `:active` pseudo-classes, because those are inherited from `#menu li a`, which you don't have at all in your CSS.

   ---

### Update 2

So I just changed `#menu` associated rules with Chrome(*! the browser you don't get this working*) on-the-go to these:

```
#menu { float: left; }
#menu ul { overflow: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#menu li { display: block; float: left; background: url(images/menu_normal.jpg) repeat-x bottom; }
#menu li a { display: block; background: transparent; height: 33px; line-height: 33px; text-align: center; width: 60px; }
#menu li a:hover { background: transparent url(images/menu_hover.jpg) repeat-x bottom; }
#menu li a:active { background: transparent url(images/menu_active.jpg) repeat-x bottom; }
```

And it works **flawlessly**! So, I'm going to say it once again, that's no bug, that's invalid CSS.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much!
But the solution kei suggested, worked also.
Could you please explain why yours is better?

Comment: And for some reason W3C CSS validator did not find any error in my initial CSS...

Comment: There is no such thing as better. That's your own preference! But I got, excuse me, pissed, seeing that there are people out there thinking that it's a bug in WebKit, where it's just invalid/improper CSS. And that means, that there are people out there, who'll use hacks instead of learning to write better, proper, standards compliant code. In long term, more hacks == more problems! So yeah, that's why I put so much effort in this.

Comment: @vlevsha, it didn't find errors, because there was none. CSS Validator only looks up incorrect/invalid properties, it cannot tell you if you're using those properties properly, and/or see if those rule relations have been screwed up.

Comment: Oh, and I can add one thing to why this is better... `:hover` pseudo-class on elements other than `<a/>` won't work in IE6. But since IE6 can be considered dead (http://ie6countdown.com/) and only WebKit had problems with your original-code, `better` comes with preference.

Comment: Thank you, Tom!
I like your explanation and appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `#menu li a:hover` to `#menu li:hover a` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a webkit bug upon a bit of searching for it. Perhaps try the method posed at the following page? http://www.simonday.com/web-design-blog/2010/10/20/css-ahover-not-working-or-crashing-webkit-chrome-safari/

Just change your code to:

```
#menu li a:hover, #menu li:hover, a {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menu ul li a:hover {
(style info here)
}
```

If this doesn't fix it, let me know!

Comment: No, it didn't fix it.
Here is the URL to the page, perhaps this will give you more information:
http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/feasibility/statue.html